# How to make a restart circuit for my circuit

Tags: transistors

I have a circuit that is on a shield type pcb and would like to create a "restart" circuit, where the circuit's power is cut and reconnected after a set period of time. I was worried that if the chips in the circuit for some reason gets stuck at least I have a way to hard restart it.

The circuit contains some ADC, PORT EXPANDERS.

The solution that I came up with have me worried on some questions.

I made a circuit like this:

[image]

The idea is pretty simple: use an NPN transistor to give power to the whole circuit.

My worry now is: The ADS1115 is an Analog to Digital Converter and connecting its ground pin to not the actual ground worries me that it would affect the reading.

How can I solve this?

I also don't like some weird interference shut the circuit down because of some sudden drop in voltage in the Base(I forgot to put a resistor in the Base).

How would I modify the Base to prevent such event? Should I pull it up and add some capacitors, and only let the GPIO to LOW to reset it?

Comment: By the way, where's the base resistor of your NPN?

Comment: I forgot to put in the picture, please assume that there is one

Comment: Use a high side P ch MOSFET switch.

Comment: @Andyaka can you explain why would i use a MOSFETS what are the advantages,

Comment: Very low saturation voltage due to having a better defined turn-on resistance (can be less than 1 milli ohm in many models). Don't do low side power management when you are using ADCs even if the on-resistance was as low as 1 milli ohm.

Comment: I see, i do not know all the MOSET modes, but basically i would need a MOSFET that is always ON (letting power through)  and when the signal is high on a GPIO  it cuts power to the circuit below. Is this what a high side P channel MOSFET do?

Comment: As an aside, you may have serious problems if you power-down your shield while it is connected to other circuits (microcontroller?) that still have power. You will need to electrically isolate all of the lines that communicate between the two power domains.

Comment: @Andyaka I did some reading on your recommendation, and have further question if you would be so kind to answer:  So for HS p ch MOSFET  circuit would go, Vcc to Source, Drain to Load, Load to Ground.  As for the gate i apply 3v3 if i want it to turn OFF and 0v to turn ON. Now upon choosing the MOSFET what should i lookfor in the data sheet that it is the one i need?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Are you saying that the components will try to draw power from the GPIO uC (the pins connected to the circuit other than Vcc and Ground.)

Comment: Yes, if you power down some components but they are connected to other components that still have power then you will likely forward bias the ESD protection circuits in the powered-down components. This can cause excessive current drain and possibly damage the powered-down components. This problem can be solved but you need to be careful.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson what are the way of solving it? what i can think of on top my head is pulling all pins down to ground. But the lines are i2c which mean they must be pulled up. Im lost there

Comment: You need to make this a new question, and show a more complete schematic of how things are connected.